# How to hanlde concurrency in Mongo DB when we have multiple instances

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, mongodb-query, race-condition

We are running a Microservice architectire with multiple instances. I have a  mongo document which consisits of list of names.If the document is not present in the collection I create a new document. But if the document is present in the collection I add the name in the existing array. But since I am using multiple instances there could be a race condition. How do I handle this, any help would be appreciated.

Skeleton of code is given below:

```
A a = repo.findById("");

if(Objects.nonNull(a))
    do some operation
else{
     a= new A();
}
a.getList.add("");
repo.save(a);
```

How do I handle concurrency in this case when multiple instances are present?

Comment: Perhaps you need a [transaction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#does-mongodb-support-transactions-) for this type of operation?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#std-label-upsert-behavior) update where the doc is modified if it exists or created if not.